# Does this strengthening of midpoint convexity have a name?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, convexity

Let $I=[a,b]$ be an interval with $b>a>0$. For a function $f\colon I\to\mathbb{R}_+$, consider the condition

$$ \forall x,y\in I,\quad \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}\ge \frac{(x+y)^2}{4xy}\cdot f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\,.$$

Note that $(x+y)^2\geq 4xy$ and $f(x)\geq 0$, so this is indeed a strengthening of midpoint convexity.
Alternatively, this condition can be thought of as a weakening of midpoint concavity of $-f$.

As an example, the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ satisfies this condition.

I was wondering if this condition has a name, or someone has encountered it.
It showed up in my research and I am looking for the right way to refer to it.

(I am mostly interested in the case where $f$ is smooth on $I$)

Thank you

Comment: The necessary condition for the inequality is of course $x^{2}f''(x)\geq 2f(x)$. But this condition is far from being sufficient as the example $f(x)=x^{2}$ shows. The "best" function is your example $1/x$.

Comment: These type of inequalities arise in  Bellman function technique for obtaining bounds of singular integral operators, especially for martingale settings. Usually one calls this inequality "a main inequality" and iterates it and obtains some interesting estimates.

Comment: @PaataIvanisvili Do you have a link to a paper which includes such an argument by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: 1) this paper of Nazarov-Treil-Volberg:
https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/Name/name1.pdf
The main inequalities are (2.3); (3.2); Section 3.3.1 item 3; (4.4)

2) I would also suggest my paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04021v1.pdf where we prove Poincare inequality 3/2. The main inequality is just Lemma 3.  

In these cases functions are 2 or more variables unlike your example which makes things much difficult.

Comment: It should be Lemma 1 from the second reference.

Answer (score 1):

This seems vaguely familiar, although I can't recall the name for it. You may like to check out the book entitled "Convex Functions and their Applications: A Contemporary Approach" by Constantin Niculescu and Lars-Erik Persson, published Springer (2006). I don't have a copy to give you specifics.

Comment: Thank you, I have online access to this book, it turns out. I am checking it.

Comment: For $x>0$, $xf(x)$ convex iff $f(\frac1x)$ convex, so I don't think the condition in the problem amounts to the convexity of $xf(x)$.